# YDKJS - How 'this' working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

I copied the code from [YDKJS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#implicitly-lost) and the authors expected output is 'oops global', but when I run this in Node, I am getting 'undefined'. Why?

```
function foo() {
  console.log(this.a);
}

var obj = {
  a: 2,
  foo: foo
};

var bar = obj.foo; // function reference/alias!

var a = "oops, global"; // `a` also property on global object

bar(); // "oops, global"
```

Comment: I didn't do any edit to the code, copied and saved as implicitLost.js and ran in terminal as 'node implicitLost.js' and got output as 'undefined'

Comment: Thanks for adding the info of how you were running it, Ramesh; it makes all the difference! :-) (I've edited it into the question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run your code in Node in the normal way:

```
node implicitLost.js
```

...Node runs your code as a *module*, not at global scope. The code shown there only outputs "oops, global" if it's run at global scope (for instance, in `<script>...</script>` in a browser). (Node also does this when you `require(...)` your code from another script.)

You can run your code at global scope by piping it into `node` instead of supplying it as an argument, using Node's REPL (note the `<` redirection):

```
node < implicitLost.js
```

Why it matters:

When run in a module, since the `var a = "oops, globals";` is at module scope, it's only defined within that module; it doesn't become a global. So `this.a` in `foo`, which is trying to access `a` on the global object, doesn't see it.

Here's that code running at global scope:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(this.a);
}

var obj = {
  a: 2,
  foo: foo
};

var bar = obj.foo; // function reference/alias!

var a = "oops, global"; // `a` also property on global object

bar(); // "oops, global"
```

And here it is running in an environment **vaguely** like the one Node runs it in:

```js
(function() {
  function foo() {
    console.log(this.a);
  }

  var obj = {
    a: 2,
    foo: foo
  };

  var bar = obj.foo; // function reference/alias!

  var a = "oops, global"; // `a` also property on global object

  bar(); // "oops, global"
})();
```

Comment: It works...Thanks  a lot!